# Select last 4 weeks of data

Tags: sql, database, hana

I have a table with column "calender_week" which holds a date. All mondays.

I need to get last 4 weeks of data. For example, today is 28th May, the query should result 4 records dated Apr 27, May 4, May 11 and May 18.

```
select "calender_week" as "week",
avg("column2") as "avg"
from testTable
where <>
```

I am unable to figure out the where condition.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select "calender_week" as "week",
avg("column2") as "avg"
from testTable
where
to_char(calender_week, 'MM')::int between to_char(to_date('01-MAY-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MM')::int -4 , to_char(to_date('01-MAY-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MM')::int
group by calender_week
```

Comment: I should have mentioned the "calender_week" is in this format "2020-05-28". I tried your code but its resulting in all weeks not last 4.

Comment: is calender_week column is in date datatype  or string datatype?

Comment: Edited the code, please use it. Please mention date the the where clause in both the places

Comment: I appreciate your help. But its not working. I am using Hana DB. The query needs to work all year, so I cannot put static dates in the query. The query must give last 4 weeks of data excluding current where "calender_week" holds monday's date.